# Module.exports function returns nothing Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I created `module.exports` function,

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Loan = require("../models/loan_model");

function unpaidList() {
  Loan.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$ePaidunpaid",
        data: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    }
  ]).then(function(data){
    console.log(data) // i am getting data here
    return data;
  })
}

 module.exports = { unpaidList };
```

This is how i am calling the function.

```
const unpaidListReq = require("../services/unpaidlist")
router.get("/", ensureAuthenticated,(req, res) => {
     let data = unpaidListReq.unpaidList()
     console.log(data)
      res.render("dashboard", {
        admin: req.user.eUserType,
        user: req.user,
      });
    })
```

But in return, while Consoling the data it returns `undefined`.
I look at the previously asked question but still getting this.

Comment: You should probably take a course in basic javascript. The function is not returning anything, which is why it returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Have `unpaidList` return a `Promise` instead:

```
function unpaidList () {
  return Loan.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$ePaidunpaid",
        data: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    }
  ])
}
```

In your handler you can then do:

```
unpaidListReq.unpaidList().then(function (data) {
  res.render("dashboard", {
    admin: req.user.eUserType,
    user: req.user
  })
})
```